# node redis get() synchronous help me

Tags: node.js, get, redis, synchronous

```
, notEnterUsers: function(){
      var users;
      this.store.get("users",function(err,result){    
        var result = JSON.parse(result);
         users = result.filter(function(element, index, arr){
          return (element.status === 0);
        });
      });

      console.log(users);
      return users;
    }
```

How to solve this problem `user = undefinded` ?

rule 1 ....

must be return users object

Answer (score 0):

With Node.js, you are supposed to use continuation passing style (CPS). This example cannot work because the callback given as a get parameter has not been executed yet when "console.log(users)" is executed.

Function notEnterUsers should have a callback parameter, and call it once the users variable has been populated. Something like:

```
, notEnterUsers: function(callback){
      var users;
      this.store.get("users",function(err,result){    
        var result = JSON.parse(result);
        users = result.filter(function(element, index, arr){
          return (element.status === 0);
        });
        callback(users);
      });
    }
```

Node.js is fundamentally asynchronous, and your scripts should try to embrace it rather than trying to mimic a synchronous behavior.